# Vmconnect.exe on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, terminal.app, hyper-v

I running Windows Server 2008 **R2** w/Hyper-V.  The Network properly works and I can access the VM's From a Hyper-V enabled 2008 Machine.  No problems there.

BUT...

I want to be able to connect to my Guest Machines from my Windows7 Pro Laptop.  I was hoping it would be simular to copy/pasting VMCONNECT.EXE to my sys32 folder. But.. It Failed saying i did not have the proper feature installed.

My Question to the Guru's of SuperUser, **Is their a way to run VMCONNECT.EXE from a (x64)Windows7 client?**

Comment: Has anyone ever used VMconnect.exe ?